# Margin-right and width:100% causes scrollbar to appear in WordPress backend

Tags: html, css, wordpress, less

I am developing a configuration page for my plugin in WordPress. I created an `<ul>` element inside a `<div>` element and placed it on my config page. The problem is, whenever I apply `margin-right` and `width:100%` to that div it causes the scroll bar to appear, the width of the list exceeds the total width of the page. As you can see at the bottom of the screenshot.

[image: The effect]

Here are the only styles I am applying (LESS):

```
div#pworks-popular-posts-list {
    display:block;
    margin:20px;
    width:100%;
    ul {
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        background-color:white;
        li {
            display:block;
            div {
                display:inline-block;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the HTML structure pulled from Chrome Dev Tools:

[image: HTML structure]

**Could you please help me with this? Thank you.**

Comment: Why don't you remove the widht:100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you are setting the div's width to be the body's width. After that you are moving it so it causes your div to go even further and that causes an overflow-X.

I wouldn't recommend setting a block element width to 100%. Block elements automatically have 100% width of their parents.

I would set a container div with a `padding: 20px;` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've found it a tiny bit more informative than Fiodor's answer so I chose this one as the correct one.

Comment: I agree it's more informative :). But be careful with this method: margin and padding are not interchangeable. Margin is outside, while padding is more inside, so if you add background, border, box-shadow, etc. to your element it will produce a different outcome.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you don't need `width:100%;` because a `display:block;` div will fill its parent's width by default. But if you want to specify it for some reason (or you plan on making it `display:inline-block;` or something) you can use `calc()` function like this: `width:calc(100% - 20px);`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `max-width:100%` instead `width:100%`.
It will reduce width according to `padding`.